# Import Tree Slash Commands from different file using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm learning how to create a discord bot using discord.py (still pretty new to python too).

I'm trying to implement multiple slash commands using app_commands Command Tree.
Here's a simplified version of my code (enough to explain my problem).

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

guild_id = 'xxxxxx'
token = 'xxxxxx'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
  print('Bot has started')

tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="listencouragements",
              description="List all encouragements messages",
              guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def listEncouragement(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  print('List: [1, 2 ,3]')

@tree.command(name="moreecouragements",
              description="More encouragements messages",
              guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def listEncouragement(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  print('This is more encouragements: [4, 5, 6]')

client.run(token)
```

I was trying to create a different file [slash.py] where I could put all tree.commands, and then import them in main file using load_extensions. Something like

```
# slash.py [This file is new, and I have
# no clue what to put here nor how to put here the commands]

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.hybrid_command()
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.display_name}!")

async def setup(bot):
  bot.add_command(hello)


#main.py
import slash

...

async def on_ready():

  await [the bot object that I dont know].load_extension(slash)

...
```

I know that exists, but I have no clue how to do that. What's the object that has the .load_extension(slash)? Am I doing this the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Extensions are for non-slash or hybrid commands. The `CommandTree` is specifically for slash commands, but you can still separate slash commands into different files.

Here's a basic setup I have used for this scenario, which requires you to setup your project using `setup.cfg` and `setup.py`. I haven't gotten this to work outside of this setup.

Using a virtual environment, you would run `pip install --editable .` (dot included) for development and run the bot with `my_bot`. You can skip `--editable` for production/deployment.

**`setup.cfg`**

```
[metadata]
name = my_bot
description = Discord bot 

[options]
packages = find:
install_requires =
    discord.py~=2.2
package_dir =
    =src

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    my_bot = my_bot:run
```

**`setup.py`**

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

**`src/my_bot/__init__.py`**

```py
import discord

from discord import app_commands

# Standard Discord client with slash commands setup
discord.VoiceClient.warn_nacl = False
token = "super-secret-discord-token"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

# While this violates the PEP8 style guide, the import is deliberately used here as
# the decorators used in the submodule depend on tree being defined.
import my_bot.commands


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")


def run():
    client.run(token)
```

**`src/my_bot/commands/__init__.py`**

```py
from . import group_one, group_two
```

**`src/my_bot/commands/group_one.py`**

```py
from discord import app_commands

from my_bot import tree

@tree.command(name="grp1")
@app_commands.describe(option_1="Option number 1")
async def grp1(interaction: discord.Interaction, *, option_1: str):
    interaction.response.send_message(f"group 1 response: {option_1}")
```

**`src/my_bot/commands/group_two.py`**

```py
from my_bot import tree

@tree.command(name="grp2")
async def grp2(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    interaction.response.send_message("group 2 response")
```

Comment: "Extensions are for non-slash or hybrid commands." Why is that the case? This is stated as obvious (and in particular the other answer here rudely assumes this as obvious), but all the help I have seen online basically says to use an `app_commands.hybrid_command` decorator when you are trying to create an extension which may be a slash command.

Comment: setup.py seems to be a non-ideal solution to me and feels a little hacky. Is there really no way to define slash commands across multiple files? I am deeply regretting deciding to clean up my  cluttered slash commands python file.

Comment: @codepringle Extensions are not for non-slash commands. App commands work just fine in extensions and cogs.

Answer (score -2):

`load_extension` is a method of `commands.Bot`.

*You could've just typed `load_extension` into the [search bar in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=load_extension) and gotten that exact same answer*

In your case, you're using a `Client` instead of a `Bot`, which doesn't have access to any of these features. You're also using `add_command()`, which is also a method of `Bot`. If you want Bot-features, use a Bot. If you don't want Bot-features, choose whichever one you want.

Also, don't load extensions in `on_ready`. Extension loading should be done by overriding `setup_hook`.

Comment: yeah, i saw that answer, but it didn't help me. that's why i tried to explain a bit what i wanted. So, if I understood correctly, I have to change from a client to a bot to use the load extension?

Comment: Yes... the method only exists on the `Bot` class so you can't use it with anything else...

Comment: It is non-obvious why the load_extension method is exclusive to Bot's. This answer is unhelpful and the italics/emphasis you've used in particular is rude.

Comment: @codepringle `load_extension` is quite literally a method of Bot, and not the base Client class. It is quite obvious why this is exclusive to Bots: `Bot` is the class that this method is on. `Bot`-specific features only exist on a `Bot`. The answer _is_ helpful because it tells OP to use a Bot instead of the Client, solving the issue. The usage of Client instead of Bot is the entire reason behind OP's problem. My answer explains _what_ the problem is, explains _why_ it is an issue, and explains how to solve it.